# Clears all the fields

Tags: java, android

I have 4 fields and 2 buttons, one of the buttons is reset, I want that when I click on the button it clears all the fields

Comment: Can you Post your XML CODE here

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.  See also: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: use the setText() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private EditText editText1, editText2, editText3, editText4;
    private Button btn_reset;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

        //javaVariable = (Cast type) findViewById(R.id.IdFromXML);
        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        btn_reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset);

        btn_reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 //Here's the actions to do when btn_reset is clicked
                 editText1.setText("");
                 editText2.setText("");
                 editText3.setText("");
                 editText4.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: While I understand that you wish to be helpful, please try to avoid answering questions that do not fit the guidelines outlined in our [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0):

Create an onClickListener to that reset button

```
Button resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View arg1) {
                textView1.setText(null);//use editText if fields are EditText
                textView2.setText(null);
                textView3.setText(null);
                textView4.setText(null);
                 }
        });
```

you can use this way on `AutoCompleteTextView`, `EditText` and `TextView`.

Comment: While I understand that you wish to be helpful, please try to avoid answering questions that do not fit the guidelines outlined in our [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: The mistake is that the questioner has not shown any evidence of trying to solve them problem themself, and appears to want us to just hand them code.  We do not wish to encourage these poor-quality questions by giving them answers.